# Is there a way to fetch data from sqlite3 database into list using python more efficiently?

Tags: sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of words (100k+ elements). In database each word has corresponding `id`. I want to get these id-s into list as well.

I'm using following function, but it is very slow:

```
def fetch_id(word_list, cursor):

   for word in word_list:
       cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM entries_table WHERE word = ?',(word,))
   data = cursor.fetchone()
   if data is not None:
       return data[0]
   else: return None
```

Is there a way to make function faster?

Comment: Is that the same indentation as in your actual code?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, but it seems that `data= crusor.fetchone()` should be in for cycle. Edited the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM entries_table WHERE word in {}".format(str(tuple(word_list))))
```